# Not able to Render Data table

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to render `DataTable` output to Shiny. Please find below explanation of my use case:

1. Connected to my database and got table data to `df` variable.
2. sent selected input from select input text box to server script.
3. Server script should take this input and get the data.

   **ui.R**

   ```
   library(shiny)
   library(RODBC)

   library(DBI)
   # Establishing connection to ORE environment
       dbconnect <- odbcConnect("orecloud", uid="XXXX", pwd="XXXXX", believeNRows=FALSE)
   # Preparing data frames to get the data and show in select input pick list
       df <- data.frame()
       df <- sqlQuery(dbconnect,"SELECT distinct cpan FROM TABLE ")
       shinyUI(fluidPage(
          headerPanel("ORE XXX Summary"),
       sidebarLayout(
       sidebarPanel(
         helpText("Please select Patient Details.."),
         selectInput("CPAN", 
                     label = "Choose patient",
                     choices = df,
                     selected = NULL),
       submitButton(text = "Submit", icon = NULL)),
       mainPanel(
       dataTableOutput("tableoutput")
       )
     )
   ))
   ```

**server.R**

1. Server script should take the input and query the data from the table
2. Render the selected data to UI
3. If I change value in UI then it should display selected input data.

   ```
   library(RODBC)

   shinyServer(
     function(input, output) {
           dbconnect <- odbcConnect("orecloud", uid="oracle",     pwd="Edvenswa2016", believeNRows=FALSE)
           df2 <- data.frame()
           input_var <- input$CPAN
           print (input_var)
           my_query <- paste("select * from CYTOKINE where CPAN=  ", input_var)
           print(myquery)
           df2 <- sqlQuery(dbconnect,myquery)
           output$tableoutput <- renderDataTable({df2})
      }
   )
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it reactive

```
df2=reactive({
input_var <- input$CPAN
my_query <- paste("select * from CYTOKINE where CPAN= ", input_var)
sqlQuery(dbconnect,myquery)
})
```

and use like `renderDataTable({df2()}) } )`

If input$CPAN is character you need `paste0("select * from CYTOKINE where CPAN= '", input_var,"'")`

Also dont forget disconect

```
session$onSessionEnded(function() {
  odbcClose(dbconnect )
})
```

Comment: @Batanicheck - Thank you!!